# Python: Exception raised even when caught in try/except clause

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, try-catch

In my code I want to catch an exception when it occurs, print some information abut the exception to the screen, and then end the script once I have done so. I tried to use something equivalent to the following code, but I don't understand why I get the traceback I do.

When executing:

```
try:
    1 / 0
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("Exception: ZeroDivisionError")
    raise Exception
```

Console reads:

```
Exception: ZeroDivisionError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#19>", line 2, in <module>
    1 / 0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#19>", line 5, in <module>
    raise Exception
Exception
```

I thought that if I catch the `ZeroDivisionError`, it would no longer be raised, and the only thing that would show is the `raise Exception` I do at the end, but both show in the console.

Why do they both show, and how do I alter the code so only the second shows, or is there a better way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The console shows the *context* here; when an exception is raised from an exception handler, Python attaches the active exception as the `__context__` attribute and Python shows that context later on if the new exception is not being handled. If you don't want the context to be shown, you need to supply a *cause* instead; you can supply an empty cause with with `raise ... from None`:

```
try:
    1 / 0
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("Exception: ZeroDivisionError")
    raise Exception from None
```

Quoting the [`raise` statement documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-raise-statement):

> The `from` clause is used for exception chaining: if given, the second expression must be another exception class or instance, which will then be attached to the raised exception as the `__cause__` attribute (which is writable). If the raised exception is not handled, both exceptions will be printed[...]
>
> A similar mechanism works implicitly if an exception is raised inside an exception handler: the previous exception is then attached as the new exception’s `__context__` attribute[...]

And from the [Exceptions documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#built-in-exceptions):

> When raising (or re-raising) an exception in an `except` clause `__context__` is automatically set to the last exception caught; if the new exception is not handled the traceback that is eventually displayed will include the originating exception(s) and the final exception.
>
> When raising a new exception (rather than using a bare `raise` to re-raise the exception currently being handled), the implicit exception context can be supplemented with an explicit cause by using `from` with `raise`:
>
> ```
> raise new_exc from original_exc
> ```
>
> The expression following from must be an exception or `None`. It will be set as `__cause__` on the raised exception. Setting `__cause__` also implicitly sets the `__suppress_context__` attribute to `True`, so that using `raise new_exc from None` effectively replaces the old exception with the new one for display purposes (e.g. converting `KeyError` to `AttributeError`), while leaving the old exception available in `__context__` for introspection when debugging.
>
> The default traceback display code shows these chained exceptions in addition to the traceback for the exception itself. An explicitly chained exception in `__cause__` is always shown when present. An implicitly chained exception in `__context__` is shown only if `__cause__` is None and `__suppress_context__` is false.

Comment: `raise Exception from None` is giving SyntaxError in python shell. Is this natural behaviour?

Comment: @SencerH.: this applies to Python 3 *only*. If you are seeing a syntax error you are using Python 2 instead.